# Virtual calls in inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance

How would i know if call to a function is resolved at compile-time or run-time from any class?

For example - In the following, From Derived class when `show()` is called, would it be resolved at runtime?

```
#include <iostream>
using std::ostream;

class Base 
{
public:
    virtual void show() {

         show(); //Call derived class 'show()'
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {

public:

    void show() {

         show(); //Call to itself, Would this call be resolved at run-time?
    }
};

ostream& operator <<(ostream &os, Base &obj)
{

    obj.Base::show();
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    Derived D;

    cout << D << endl;
}
```

Comment: Just compile into an assembly listing with -S. It is very easy to see the difference between a virtual dispatch (run-time) and a normal function call.

Comment: @Mikael: "virtual dispatch...normal function call" - if those are the options, it really doesn't matter from a performance perspective: what can matter is when it's virtual dispatch versus inlining.

Comment: I'm concerned you're misunderstanding virtual dispatch: `Base::show()` shouldn't call show()... it is not invoked when a virtual overload is available, the derived-class implementation is called directly.  `Derived::show()` shouldn't called `show()` - that would recurse infinitely until the stack space ran out.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you are calling a member function through an object of the concrete type (i.e. no pointer), the static type is known thus the compiler resolves the right function at compile time.
The only time virtual functions are resolved at runtime is when you are calling them on a pointer to an object, using polymorphism.

In your example the calls to show() are made through the "this" pointer and subsequently they would be resolved at runtime. Consider that there could always be a class even further down the inheritance chain that implements show().

The explicitly qualified call "obj.Base::show()" is obviously resolved at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever the compiler can figure out which overload of your function to call, it will. It is guaranteed to be able to do that when

- it has the complete type of the object (e.g. `Foo foo; foo.bar();`)
- you tell it which overload to call (e.g. `Foo foo; foo.Bar::bar();`)

but it *may* be able to do that in cases where it's less obvious - i.e. if it can figure out that "this pointer to `Foo` really always points to `Bar`". That's called *devirtualization* and is part of the night goggles an optimizing compiler has. Depending on your compiler, and depending on your real-world code, it may be possible to perform this optimization - and call your function directly without passing through the vtable.

Comment: In those cases you can use CRTP (Curiously Recurring Template Pattern) if you want to be guaranteed static polymorphism no matter the degree of magic going on inside the compiler.

Comment: if you want to be guaranteed that, sure, but CRTP isn't always an option in real life, and devirtualization isn't something you should count on - it's something that can be nice if the compiler can do it for you

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, in your code obj.Base::show() is being resolved at compile time because of the explicit call to the Base function. If you want to resolve this at run time then you can use a pointer to the Base and pass to it a pointer to a Derived.

For example:

```
ostream& operator <<(ostream &os, Base *obj)
{    
    obj->show();
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    Derived D;    
    cout << &D << endl;
}
```

I am not sure what you are trying to do. From your code it seems that you want to call the derived (polymorphic, resolved at runtime version) from your base class 'show()' function. There is no need for this since the Derived version is automatically called because it is virtual.